# Output the result of PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

My task is to display the output of php script in HTML.
It seems like, there is a problem with My PHP code, which i cant make out.
Please take a look at my code and let me know where I am going wrong.thanks in advance
Here is my HTML

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="NetOptInput1.html">
<label>  Please wait. Your data is being processed.
</label><br>
<br>
<label>Token Number for the submitted Data set:</label><br />
<?php
include("GetToken.php");
echo $result;
?> <br>
<div style="text-align: center"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Home" class="submit" onClick = "gotoResults()">
<div class="spacer"></div> 
</form>
```

and here is my PHP

```
<?php
function get_value_of($Token Number)
{
 $lines = file('Token.txt');
 foreach (array_values($lines) AS $line)
 {
      list($key, $val) = explode('=', trim($line) );     
      if (trim($key) == $Token Number)
      {
            return $val;
      }
 }
 return false;
} 
?>
```

Comment: and the problem would be ??

Comment: $Token Number - Syntax Error?
Look up the echo-construct or the print function in the manual. Or maybe even consider actual learning php.

Comment: What you are currently doing wrong is that you not searching and fixing the error for yourself - regardless if it might take a whole night

Comment: Where are you calling the `get_value_of()` function?

Comment: Where are you setting `$result`? Is the second PHP the contents of `GetToken.php`?

Comment: Ask one of your classmates.

Comment: You don't need to use `array_values()` in your `foreach` loop. Just do `foreach($lines as $line)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing the space of $Token Number variable...let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have some complexeties on your code. Let me explain.

First thing is that, you have errors on your PHP code
Instead of calling `get_value_of($Token Number)`, call it as `get_value_of($Token)`. This suffices and do the same on your `if` control structure like this  `if (trim($key) == $Token)`

Second thing is that you are not calling your **`get_value_of($Token)`** function, so without calling this your code eventually will not be executed. So just initiate a call. Like below.

```
<?php
function get_value_of($Token)
{
    $lines = file('Token.txt');
    foreach (array_values($lines) as $line)
    {
        list($key, $val) = explode('=', trim($line) );
      if (trim($key) == $Token)
      {
          return $val;
      }
 }
    return false;
}

get_value_of(30); // call your function here
?>
```